# Print Interactive Reporting in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, printing, oracle-apex

hello i want to press a button to print a report in apex oracle, maybe someone did similar ??
I use a java script, but it doesn't really work for me.

```html
 var navCollapsed = 0;
        if ($("body").hasClass("js-navExpanded")) {
            $("#t_Button_navControl").click();
            navCollapsed = 1;
        };
        setTimeout(3000);
        $("#t_Header").hide();
        $("#t_Body_nav").hide();
        $("#t_Body_title").hide();
        $("#t_Body_content_offset").hide();
        $(".a-IRR-toolbar").hide();
        $("#LINK").hide();
        $('td[headers="LINK"]').hide();
        $(".t-Button").hide();
        $(".t-Footer").hide();
        window.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will be possible directly or not. But you can do one thing. Download the report in pdf/csv format and then print it.

You can also explore the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldapp_rpt_print.htm#HTMDB25375) for more in depth info about printing reports in Apex.

Answer (score -1):

It's work fine with your code. You can use dynamic action 
[Apex dynamic action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNUBz.png)

or you can enable printing Property from report attribute

[printing Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd93J.png)

[Demo](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100165:1)

I need at least 10 reputation to post images.